# flex4 sdk in flexbuilder3, debugger partially works

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

If I changed used in one of my project sdk to current sdk4 beta, set breakpoint and stop on them every occurrences of mx.* packages are labeled "[no source]". Is known any trick to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Flex Builder isn't figuring it out by itself, but you can manually set the source path of any swc on the library path (you have to do this for each project):

- Right-click on the project, Properties
- Flex Build Path property page
- Library Path tab
- Expand the "Flex 4.0" node at the top, then expand the swc that you want to attach source to
- Double-click the "Source attachment" line, and specify the root dir of the source, e.g. `C:\...\mysdk\frameworks\projects\framework\src`